# iOS7 UINavigationBar tintColor changes to max .8 when set

Tags: iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I've run into a weird bug in my program - everything works fine on the simulator, but when I run my app on an actual device, the *tintColor* of my *UINavigationBar* maxes out at .8 for the red, green, and blue channels. Here is a snippet of the code that I used to test:

```
UIColor *navcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:140/255.0 green:193/255.0 blue:227/255.0 alpha:1];

if(IOS7()) {
    hnvc.navigationBar.barTintColor = navcolor;
    hnvc.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:146/255.0 green:53/255.0 blue:40/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    hnvc.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0;
    hnvc.navigationBar.opaque = YES;
    hnvc.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;

    hnvc.navigationBar.tintColor = color;

    NSLog(@"%d", hnvc.navigationBar.translucent);
    NSLog(@"%@", color);
    NSLog(@"%@", hnvc.navigationBar.tintColor);

    const CGFloat* components1 = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    NSLog(@ "A: %f, R: %f G: %f B: %f", CGColorGetAlpha(color.CGColor), components1[0], components1[1], components1[2]);

    const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(hnvc.navigationBar.tintColor.CGColor);
    NSLog(@ "A: %f, R: %f G: %f B: %f", CGColorGetAlpha(hnvc.navigationBar.tintColor.CGColor), components[0], components[1], components[2]);

}
```

As you can see, I tested a lot of different properties, but none of them seem to work. The output when I run this app in the simulator (iPhone 4-inch, iOS 7.1) is:

```
2014-07-06 21:52:54.096 L'Allegro[16650:60b] 0
2014-07-06 21:52:54.097 L'Allegro[16650:60b] UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1
2014-07-06 21:52:54.098 L'Allegro[16650:60b] UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1
2014-07-06 21:52:54.098 L'Allegro[16650:60b] A: 1.000000, R: 1.000000 G: 1.000000 B: 1.000000
2014-07-06 21:52:54.099 L'Allegro[16650:60b] A: 1.000000, R: 1.000000 G: 1.000000 B: 1.000000
```

However, when I run the app on my iPod touch 5th Gen (iOS 7.0), the output is:

```
2014-07-06 21:55:09.904 L'Allegro[3620:60b] 0
2014-07-06 21:55:09.908 L'Allegro[3620:60b] UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1
2014-07-06 21:55:09.910 L'Allegro[3620:60b] UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.8 0.8 0.8 1
2014-07-06 21:55:09.912 L'Allegro[3620:60b] A: 1.000000, R: 1.000000 G: 1.000000 B: 1.000000
2014-07-06 21:55:09.914 L'Allegro[3620:60b] A: 1.000000, R: 0.800000 G: 0.800000 B: 0.800000
```

The same goes for any value of 1.0 that I try to set (i.e. if I use [UIColor redColor], the red component gets set to .8 instead of 1.0).

The result of this is that in the simulator, the bar button items on the navigation bar appear to be white, but show up in a light gray on my actual device.

I've been working at this for hours, and it's really frustrating that something as trivial as changing the color of my UIBarButtonItem to white can take such a long time so any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in iOS7 to current iOS version supported navigation bar color

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.f green:231.0/255.f blue:231.0/255.f alpha:1]];
```

is for color set at navigation controller.

but on that controller set perfect bar color so you have to set on viewdidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm not actually trying to set the color of the navigation bar though; I"m trying to set the tintColor so that I can change the color of the text of the "Back" button that shows up (the UIBarButtonItem's). Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: only use in iOS7 to later self.window.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor]; its not work on iOS6.